# Python: Get 2 filenames from command line using OptionParser

Tags: python, command-line

I want to use a program like this:

```
python myprg.py -f1 t1.txt -f2 t.csv
```

where f1, f2 are filenames.
I have the following code:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
def main():
    optparser = OptionParser()
    optparser.add_option('-f1', '--inputFile1',
                         dest='input1',
                         help='file to be checked',
                         default=None)
    optparser.add_option('-f2', '--inputFile2',
                         dest='input2',
                         help='basis csv file',
                         default='defaut.csv')
....
....
```

I read in documentation that -f reads FILE types, but if I put -f in both, it gives an error of conflict.
Any suggestions on how to proceed?
Thank you!

Comment: What error do you get? Please [edit] it into the question, give a [mcve].

Comment: "an error of conflict" is totally unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html), optparse does not support multiple letters with single hyphen (-).

> Some option syntaxes that the world has seen include:
>
> - a hyphen followed by a few letters, e.g. -pf (this is not the same as    multiple options merged into a single argument)
> - a hyphen followed by a whole word, e.g. -file (this is technically    equivalent to the previous syntax, but they aren’t usually seen in
>     the same program)
> - a plus sign followed by a single letter, or a few letters, or a word,    e.g. +f, +rgb
> - a slash followed by a letter, or a few letters, or a word, e.g. /f,    /file
>
> These option syntaxes are not supported by optparse, and they never
>   will be.

You should change option keys something like that  `-f1` to `-a` , `-f2` to `-b`.

```
python myprg.py -a t1.txt -b t.csv 



optparser.add_option('-a', '--inputFile1',
                         dest='input1',
                         help='file to be checked',
                         default=None)
optparser.add_option('-b', '--inputFile2',
                         dest='input2',
                         help='basis csv file',
                         default='defaut.csv')
```